# Creating full html page with VSCode and marked

Tags: html, css, markdown, visual-studio-code, javascript-marked

I followed the [Compiling Markdown into HTML](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/markdown#_using-your-own-css) tutorial for VSCode. I managed to create a html file with `marked my.md -o my.html` but this file only contains the contents of my markdown. By this I mean there is no styling, no `html` and `body` tags. The html is *incomplete*.

Do you know how to create a full html page? The [github for marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) lists only the `-o` option. Can it even render a full html?

Comment: But does it render paragraphs as p-tags, headers with h1-6 tags and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Markdown renders to an HTML fragment, not an HTML document. In fact. most Markdown parsers (including the original reference implementation) only output HTML fragments.

The [rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state in part:

> HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing* format.

Wrapping an HTML fragment in `<html>` and `<body>` tags is *publishing* and out-of-scope for Markdown. It is your responsibility to wrap the fragment in a document template.

Among Markdown parsers, there are a few exceptions, but those tools are usually more than simply a Markdown parser. They tend to be *publishing* platforms and often support more than only Markdown . They combine Markdown parsing, templating (where the Markdown output is inserted into the template as one variable) and various other features to create a complete publishing tool (see Pandoc for example). Marked is not such a tool. It is a Markdown parser only. However, there may be other tools out there that wrap Marked as part of a publishing tool. Or you can build your own custom solution (using Marked) for your specific needs.

If that is the case, then why would Marked (or any other Markdown parser) have a command-line interface? So you can pipe the output to other tools.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this distinction and it actually makes a lot of sense. I thought if the preview in VSCode is nicely styled but the html output not so I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Marked only handles basic markdown content to html content conversion, and expects you to bring your own document and styling. You can throw together a simple node script to handle this:

```
// convertMd.js
var marked = require('marked')
var fs = require('fs')

const inFile = process.argv[2]
const outFile = process.argv[3]

const inputContent = fs.readFileSync(inFile, 'utf8')

const content = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
${marked(inputContent)}
</body>
</html>`

fs.writeFileSync(outFile, content)
```

where the tasks.json would be:

```
{
  // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  //  for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "node",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": ["./convertMd.js", "sample.md", "sample.html"],
  "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Other command line tools may provide a more complete html output.

Comment: After some trial and error I managed to run this and it worked like a charm ;-) I need to take a closer look at tasks and node scripting because currently I don't understand a single line. I'm having a really hard time to accept any of the answers as they are both very helpful.